# I can't move image to top-left of screen with css

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use an image of my logo on the webpage and put it into the top-left of my webpage but it seems to have a space on the top and left side of the image and I want it flush just like dropbox.com does it
Here's the html:
`

```
<body>
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="img/pd3-1.jpg"></a>
      </div>
    </nav> 
</body>
```

`

I've tried many things such as remove padding/margin, change position, float, I'm new to coding so I can't seem to fix it or find an answer

[image]

Comment: have you checked to see if the image itself has any dead space/white space thats causing the spacing issue?

Comment: Yes I created it in Adobe Expression with a height of 100 and width of 300, the image in the microsoft photos have no space on the outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using position relative and position absolute may be your answer.
we position the container relative, allowing our absolute positioning to be relative to this container.
I added a background so you can see the position of the logo better.

```css
nav{width:100%;position:relative;}
.logo{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:150px;height:150px;background:#ededed;}
```

```html
<body>
    <nav>
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="index.html"><img src="img/pd3-1.jpg"></a>
      </div>
    </nav> 
</body>
```

Also make sure your css is being linked in the head of your index file as without this no styles will pass through to the page.

Final Result
After reviewing the issue with Jacob on jsfiddle we established that he was not including the css in the head. Adding the css to the head of the site fixed the issue and the custom styles are now styling the image correctly.

Comment: I ran this code just now and not even the background appeared also no change occurred

Comment: can you provide a code sample on here or jsfiddle as the code you provided does not show any background integrations, also remember you dont need the width, height or background colour as that was just for you to see positioning.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=p7UjiiFGbz

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me figure this out

Answer (score 1):

Remove the default margin of the body element:

```
body {margin:0;}
```

Comment: It didn't work, I also tried * {margin: 0;}

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the space of the parent elements. Did you remove all of them?

for example:

```
body, body * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes I've targeted everything, body, .logo, a, in multiple different variations

Comment: Are you able to share more detailed code here? maybe you didn't consider any of them.

Comment: did you get resolve this?